# If $P$ and $Q$ are invertible matrices $PQ=-QP$, then which claim about their traces is true?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, trace

If $P$, $Q$ are invertible and $PQ=-QP$, then what can we say about traces of $P$ and $Q$.

I faced this question in an exam but according to me this question is wrong as $Q=-P^{-1}QP$, which implies $\det(Q)=0$ and it implies $Q$ is not invertible? But it is given invertible in hypothesis.

Options were both traces $0$, both $1$, $Tr(Q)\neq Tr(P)$ or $Tr(Q)=-Tr(P)$

Comment: What you know is $$\det Q=(-1)^n\det (P^{-1}QP)=(-1)^n\det(Q)\implies \;n\;\text{ is even or}\;\text{char}\,\Bbb F=2 $$ with $\;\Bbb F\;$ the field of definition.

Comment: but $\det(AB) =\det(A)\det(B)$ and $det(P^{-1})=det(P)?$

Comment: No, of course not: $$|P^{-1}QP|=|P^{-1}||Q||P|=|P|^{-1}|P||Q|=1\cdot|Q| ...$$

Answer (score 3):

use the fact that $tr(AB)=tr(BA)$ so $tr(-P^{-1}QP)=-tr(Q)$.

Answer (score 3):

Note that we can only deduce that $Q=0$ (as you did using the determinant) if $P$ and $Q$ have an *even* size. In particular, note that $\det(-Q)= (-1)^n \det(Q)$, where $Q$ has size $n$.  For a specific example, take
$$
P = \pmatrix{0&1\\1&0}, \quad Q = \pmatrix{1&0\\0&-1}
$$

However, using your equation, we could take the **trace** of both sides to find that $Q$ has trace $0$. Symmetrically, we may argue that $P$ also has trace $0$.

Answer (score 3):

Pre-multiply by $P^{-1}$ to  get $Q=P^{-1}(-Q)P$ which implies that matrices $Q$ and $-Q$ are similar, so $tr(Q)=tr(-Q)\implies tr(Q)=0$. Similarly you can get $tr(P)=0$ also.